# Android Studio mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: android, android-studio, osx-mavericks

how can i solve this:

“Android Studio” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Open System Preferences -> Security & Privacy, then Change "Allow apps downloaded from:" to Anywhere.

Comment: This is not necessary. If you open Security & Privacy, in the General tab there's a button that says "Open Anyway" next to the last alert of  an app that couldn't be opened. You don't need to change the policy.

Comment: I didnt have the "Open Anyway" button, the solution was to press Ctrl key before clicking on the Android Studio Icon as it says on the Mavericks Help's manual.

Comment: You can also do CTRL + Right click and select open. This only has to be done the first time, after that it will trust the app.

Comment: Don't change the policy just for a single exception. Just open it, as suggested by @Mgamerz, with CTRL and right click.

Answer (score 0):

Right click > Open.

Or, go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy and press 'Open Anyway'.